# redirect URI for google sigin

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, authentication

I am new to app development and I am learning social signin. I was trying to setup google sign-in for my app.

I want to understand what should be the redirect signin/signout URI for my app.

In lots of internet matierals, I came across using http://localhost: and also for production, its mentioned as  https://yourwebsite.com.  But, I am not able to understand what I should be specifying for the app in case of production. What kind of URI will my app have? Where can I find it.

Thanks in advance.

I am not sure what to use for production redirect URI.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect URL will always be of the following format:
`PROTOCOL://HOST/PATH`. For example `https://myawesomesite.com/oauth`.

What you need to find out is the `PATH`. This depends on the `OAuth` library you are using for social login. Check the documentation and example of the oauth library you are using and find the path from there. After that there are two possibilities:

1. For development, when you are running your app on localhost you will be running it on some port e.g. `8080`. In that case you can use the following redirect URLs: `http://localhost:8080/path` or `http://127.0.0.1:8080/path`.
2. For production, you will be running your app on a server which will be connected to some domain such as `myawesomesite.com`. Now if you configure HTTPS correctly, your app will run on port `443`, that is the default HTTPS port. Therefore your redirect URL will be `https://myawesomesite.com/path`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using AWS Amplify. I am not deploying an custom app on the server as such. What kind of redirect URI should I use  when I am using AWS amplify, or where can I find the redirect URI? I am a bit confused here still.